# PHP calling Python, returning multiple values

Tags: php, python, arrays, soap

I'm setting up a SOAP server using php. In processing the SOAP requests, I will then need to call some existing python scripts. These scripts have typically returned 3 values: success, description, and data.

How do I pass all three values back to the php?

My request is:

```
exec('python test.py', $output);
```

test.py does:

```
from getData import getData

status, description, data = getData()

return status, description, data
```

and my existing python looks something like this:

```
def getData():
    database = Database()

    # get all the Data from the db
    data = database.getData()

    if data is None:
        return False, "...notes...", ""

    return True, "...notes...", data
```

I'm not sure the return in test.py is correct. But even if it is, when I look at var_dump($output) all I see is "Array"

Anyone have any ideas?

TIA,

Brian

Comment: What happens when you execute `python test.py` on the command line?

Comment: Good point. I did have print at first but changed to return. If I do a return I get "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `exec()` call receives shell output into the variable `$output`, it has no way of receiving the returned strings from the Python functions.  Instead of returning them,  you must print them, and each printed line will go into the `exec()` array `$output`.

The main script must print the values to stdout:

```
from getData import getData
status, description, data = getData()

# Print the values
print("STATUS:", status)
print("DESCRIPTION:", description)
print("DATA:", data)
```

In PHP, examine the output you get back:

```
exec("python test.py", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

You will need to format your `print` statements in Python into something you can easily parse values from in PHP, such as one thing per line, or key: value pairs that you can `explode()`.

Comment: Ok, T/F would go to the exec's return_var then? If the "notes" that I listed in my example is a multi-line, variable length string, will I still be able to access this through $output[0] and the data in $output[1]?

Comment: @BrianCox Sorry, I had that wrong. Your call to `getData()` can work as you had it, but you need to print the values from the python script.  If you are expecting multi-line strings, you will need to devise some method to parse them out, like a `key: value` pair.

Comment: If the output is going to be complex, I'd think about encoding the python output into JSON, which would make reading it in PHP a bit easier.

Comment: When I do (from the command line):python test_get_bcas.py 
I get:
('STATUS:', True, '\n') 
('DESCRIPTION:', 'Success', '\n') 
('DATA:', ['val1', 'val2'], '\n')

Works as I would expect.

But in the php, var_dump($output) gives me:
array(0) { } 

Btw, thanks for the help with this. Python and PHP are both fairly new to me. I think I know just enough to be dangerous! :)

Comment: @Michael apologies for the horrible formatting. I can repost if it helps.

Comment: @BrianCox if you have python 2.x, don't use `()` on the print statements, and the `"\n"` are not necessary either.  e.g. `print "STATUS:",True`

Comment: @BrianCox if you get no output, make sure PHP is actually able to find the file and execute it.  In my tests, this should work perfectly.

Comment: @Michael It does seem like there is a further error. I'll look into it and update here as necessary.

Comment: @ernie JSON may be worth looking into as well. Thank you both for the sugggestions!

Comment: @Michael, the remaining error has to do with permissions accessing the database through this method. Sending canned data back instead did work. Thanks again for the tips!